# Routing keys parameter in RabbitMqBundle

Tags: php, symfony, rabbitmq, symfony-2.1

I use Symfony 2.1.8 and the RabbitMqBundle.

I'm trying to add `routing_keys` parameter into `config.yml` like this:

```yaml
old_sound_rabbit_mq:
connections:
    default:
        host:      'localhost'
        port:      5672
        user:      'guest'
        password:  'guest'
        vhost:     '/'
producers:
    twitter_metrics:
        connection: default
        exchange_options: {name: 'social-networks', type: topic}
consumers:
    twitter_metrics:
        connection: default
        exchange_options:
            name: 'social-networks'
            type: topic
        queue_options:
            name: 'twitter-metrics-queue'
            routing_keys:
              - 'metrics.twitter'
        callback: twitter_metrics_service
```

I tried adding `routing_keys` parameter into `producers` too and variants only in consumers and producers. But when I try to use symfony2 console, I get this:

> [Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]
>   Unrecognized options "routing_keys" under "old_sound_rabbit_mq.consumers.twitter_metrics.queue_options"

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was resolved after last today updates of RabbitMqBundle. If you had the same problem, try `php composer.phar update` command in your symfony app path.